# “I knocked and opened a door with a hand.“

Tags: meaning

[Should the object be singular?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/303907/should-the-object-be-singular?noredirect=1#comment569048_303907)

> I knocked and opened a door with a hand.

According to the answer, it means I knocked and opened a door only with the same hand. But I think it can mean I knocked the door with a left hand and I opened the door with a right hand, or vice versa.

But according to the answer, it should be only one hand. So I’m really confused. What’s the truth? ‘I tasted and smelled a candy’ and ‘I knocked and opened a door with a hand’ are thought to be the same case by me.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP seems to have a habit of inventing completely unnatural sentences and trying to extract improbable meanings from them.

Comment: The cited text is "unnaturally phrased", as @Kate says. In the unlikely event that it was important to convey the specific detail here, *I knocked and opened a [the?] door **using the same** hand* would achieve that. But why would anyone want to? And what useful principle of English syntax is being illustrated here?

Comment: "**A** hand" (or "a piece of candy", or anything) always means **one** hand (or piece of candy, or whatever).  It never means "one thing, and then a different thing."

Answer (score 3):

Your sentence is not natural. If you said it I'd assume you meant

> I knocked, and opened the door with a hand.

Two actions described.  The first is knocking (you might have used a hand, or a cane to knock)  The second is opening the door, which you did using a hand (Whose hand?  I don't know.  Perhaps you collect dead people's hands to open doors with. Gruesome!)

But I'd know you weren't a native speaker. Why mention "with a hand"? How do you normally open doors in your country? Clearly these can't be automatic doors, because you don't knock on automatic doors. Now suppose you said:

> I shouted and then opened the door with my foot, because my hands were full.

Do you think "I shouted with my foot".  Of course not.

Comment: I can’t understand because ‘I ate an apple three times’ can mean ‘I ate three apples in total’ it is ‘an apple’ doesn’t it mean ‘I ate the same apple three times?

Comment: And I use ‘with a hand’ to differentiate ‘automatically opened doors.’

Comment: ‘I ate an apple three times" means "the same apple three times" which is impossible so it means nothing.   You don't knock on automatic doors, so again it doesn't make sense.

Comment: But I always eat an apple in the morning. It doesn’t mean I always eat the same apple.

Comment: Or in this case, should I say I always eat apples in the morning?

Comment: What do you **actually** want to say.  Nothing with apples please.  A real situation that you have really been in:  perhaps a conversation or an English test.

Comment: It’s for English test.

Comment: What is the question in the text?

Comment: I often eat an apple/apples in the morning. It’s a real problem. If I eat an apple every morning, should I say I always eat apples in the morning because I don’t eat the same apple?

Comment: If that was what you wanted to ask about, what's the point of these strange sentences about hands and candies? You can say _I eat an apple every morning_ or _I eat an apple three times a day_ but not _I eat an apple three times_.